# How can I remove the "&" that keep appearing when the URL is printed?

Tags: swift, url, nsurlcomponents

How can I remove the "&" that keep appearing when the URL is printed? Why is it even appearing?

```
var url = URLComponents()
    url.scheme = "http"
    url.host = "api.openweathermap.org"

    url.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "/data", value: ""),
        URLQueryItem(name: "/2.5", value: ""),

        URLQueryItem(name: "/weather?", value: ""),
        URLQueryItem(name: "lat", value: "35"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "lon", value: "-139")
    ]

    print(url.string!)

// http://api.openweathermap.org?/data=&/2.5=&/weather?=&lat=35&lon=-139
```

**New Issue:**

How can I turn the following coordinate into a string?

(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)

Comment: You are misusing `URLQueryItem`. You only want that for `lat` and `lon`.

Answer (score 2):

```
/data/2.5/weather
```

is the path, not a query item.
Try:

```
var url = URLComponents()
url.scheme = "http"
url.host = "api.openweathermap.org"
url.path = "/data/2.5/weather"

url.queryItems = [

    URLQueryItem(name: "lat", value: "35"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "lon", value: "-139")
]
```

Comment: Now I get the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The path needs to start with `/`. `url.path = "/data/2.5/weather"`

Comment: Ok, now I just need to turn the coordinates received by the device into strings, do you know how this can be done?

Comment: @JuniorRickson That's a completely new question. Indicate that this question has been solved by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. If you have a new question a lot of research and try some things. If you get stuck, post a new question with relevant code and clearly explain your issue.